# what can be a good icon for indicating postpone?

Tags: symbols

I make to-do lists at work on post its for things I have to do.
e.g.

- Make the software more usable.
- Change radioboxes to checkboxes.
- Refactor code.
- Commit and merge with master branch.

Now I have completed the 2nd task and have striked it through or I make a tick mark on it. Next I want to do the 3rd and 4th task. I want to postpone the 1st one. What kind of symbol should I draw on the post-it to best indicate that I have postponed the task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like the II sign depicting pause on the players. Its advantage is that you can place a "stop" square or other signs of similar style, so the all bunch of signs will be successive.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could place one of the icons shown below above your post-it? I like the clock idea, by adding the arrow circling the clock it could be interpreted as rescheduling.

[image: Postpone icon ideas, back arrow and clock reschedule]

Answer (score 0):

I use a capital P and circle it, beside the task!

Or on a second thought maybe put an icon of a old school clock?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use below icons and modify it to show the postpone status

clock

[image]

or

Hour Glass

[image]

Note: All icons are taken from the internet. Please check copyright stuff before using it directly. These icons are just for inspiring you. Do not use directly as it is.